# How to Dynamically Show 404 in Angular

Tags: angular7, angular-router

I searched over and over again, but maybe my search terms were incorrect, because nothing turned up. I want to dynamically show my 404 component depending on the results of an HTTP request.

I realize that I can do this by redirect the user to my 404 page, but is there any way I can render the component without changing the URL?

Something like `/people/<nonexistent id>`

1. Perform HTTP request
2. If person exists, proceed as normal
3. If person doesn't exist, render 404 *without changing the URL*

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Never mind, I found the answer.

The solution is to use`router.navigate` with the option `skipLocationChange` set to `true`. This tells Angular to reroute without changing the URL in the browser navbar.

https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#skipLocationChange